# Pointers, Custom Classes, Seg Fault 11s

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Trying to design a simple linked list.  Node declared as such:

```
class Node
{
public:
friend class CRevList;

Node() {m_next = 0;  m_prev = 0;}
Node(const T &t) {m_payload = t;  m_next = 0;  m_prev = 0;}

T Data() {return m_payload;}
const T Data() const { return m_payload; }

private:
Node    *m_next;
Node    *m_prev;
T       m_payload;
};
```

So m_next points to the next item in the list and m_payload holds its value.  m_head is declared as this:

```
private:
Node    m_head;             // Head node
```

Incomplete function to put a new node at the front of the list with payload t:

```
void PushFront(const T &t)
{
  Node *newnode = Node(t);
  m_head.m_next = newnode;
}
```

The above should declare a new node with a payload of t, and set the m_head's next node to the new node.  I'm not yet linking it to the rest of the list, just want to get at least 1 node working.

```
int GetFirst() //get value of first item in list.
{
  Node *firstnode = m_head.m_next;
  int payload = firstnode->m_payload;
  return payload; //m_head.m_next->m_payload;
}
```

This is trying to get the first node in the list, fetch it's payload, and return... which gives a Seg Fault 11 error.

I'm pretty sure it's a problem with how I'm doing the pointers, and I have a general understanding of them, but having read documentation I'm still not sure how to approach the error.

Thanks!

Comment: _`Node *newnode = Node(t);`_ Does this even compile?

Comment: Yes, it compiles.  Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: Could you put your example onto Ideone, to prove it compiles, please?

Comment: Yes there's something wrong with it, `Node(t)` is a Node, so can't be assigned to a `Node*` because that's not the same type. Maybe you meant `Node* newnode = new Node(t);` instead? Show the real code, not small snippets of something that is approximately the same, but not actually the same. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: 4 files, RevList.h: http://ideone.com/e.js/XwA5pM  random.h http://ideone.com/e.js/AZIRm5  random.cpp http://ideone.com/e.js/px5bO9 and main.cpp http://ideone.com/e.js/kyOXYL it makes with http://ideone.com/e.js/3Gb7eC  When I compile it builds, when I run it segfaults when I try to access the data in the node.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the help of Jonathan Wakely:

PushFront needed to be

```
Node *newnode = new Node(t);
```

Additionally, there was an problem trying to access the private variable with

```
int payload = nextnode->m_payload;
```

I needed to use the public method

```
int payload = nextnode->Data();
```

Comment: To add, `nullptr` is a better alternative than setting a pointer to `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Poriferous!